# R- work inside text

Tags: r, text

I have a table with text like:

```
tt<-data.frame(a=c("esta es la unica lista que voy a hacer","esta es la 2da unica"))
```

I need to keep only the words that have more than 3 characters:

```
tt<-data.frame(a=c("esta unica lista hacer","esta unica"))
```

In this case I have no clue of how to do it. I know I have to use nchar and a loop over the table and inside another loop over the words.

Comment: `tt[] <- gsub('\\b\\w{1,3}\\s', '', tt$a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tt)
tt[,a:=gsub("\\s+"," ",gsub("\\b\\w{1,3}\\b","",a))]

                        a
1: esta unica lista hacer
2:             esta unica
```

Another option, depending on exactly the output you want, is:

```
library(data.table)  #1.9.5+
tt[,tstrsplit(gsub("\\b\\w{1,3}\\b","",a),split="\\s+")]

     V1    V2    V3    V4
1: esta unica lista hacer
2: esta unica    NA    NA
```

---

Edit: After much tussling at the encouragement of @rawr, here is a way to get at the problem more directly (include 4-letter words instead of exclude 3-letter words)

```
tt[,a:=lapply(regmatches(a, gregexpr('\\b\\w{4,}\\b',a)),paste0,collapse=" ")]
```

Comment: you only need one gsub `tt[, a := gsub('\\b\\w{1,3}\\s', '', a)]`

Comment: @rawr what about the string `"long words excepting end"`

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to account both cases in one `gsub`, I'm sure there is one though

Comment: maybe just add that the space is optional? `gsub('\\b\\w{1,3}\\b\\s?', '', tt$a)` or `regmatches(tt$a, gregexpr('\\b\\w{4,}\\b', tt$a))` for binding into a data frame like your second example. I was just going by the example given

Comment: all of these are about `removing words with <= 3 characters` when the question was actually `keeping words with > 3 characters` :}

Comment: did you have the comma in there?

Answer (score 3):

It's not too tricky if you break it into chunks.  First use `apply` to iterate over each row of the data frame.  Then for each row, break strings into words, select the long ones, paste back into a string, and return the result:

```
tt<-data.frame(a=c("esta es la unica lista que voy a hacer","esta es la 2da unica"))
library(stringr)

tt$a <- lapply(tt$a, function(x) {
  l <- unlist(str_split(x, " "))
  t <- l[which(nchar(l)>3)]
  return(paste0(t, collapse=" "))
})
```

Comment: almost, I need to keep the same format, a data frame.

Comment: You can assign the result to a data frame column as shown in new edit.

Comment: I get this  result: [1] "esta unica lista hacer" "esta unica"

Comment: The edited answer (with the assignment to `tt$a`) returns a dataframe `tt`. I like this solution, but I think that the combination of `paste0()` and `collapse=" "` is somewhat awkward. Simply using `paste()` without the zero and without `collapse` is sufficient.

Comment: If you type `tt$a` then yes, you will get the column as a vector.  To see the whole data frame, type `tt`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using the **qdapRegex** package.

```
library(qdapRegex)

tt <- data.frame(a = c('esta es la unica lista que voy a hacer', 'esta es la 2da unica'))
tt$a <- rm_nchar_words(tt$a, 1, pattern = '\\b\\w{1,3}\\b')
tt

#                        a
# 1 esta unica lista hacer
# 2             esta unica
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the **quanteda** package, that tokenizes the texts in your data.frame and removes the tokens whose length is <= 3.  Note that I have specified `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` here in the `data.frame()` -- although this would work equally fine if you were operating directly on a character vector.

```
require(quanteda)
tt <- data.frame(a=c("esta es la unica lista que voy a hacer", "esta es la 2da unica"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ttTokenized <- tokenize(tt$a)
(ttTokenized <- sapply(ttTokenized, function(x) x[nchar(x) > 3]))
## [[1]]
## [1] "esta"  "unica" "lista" "hacer"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "esta"  "unica"
```

If you want the original-looking texts rather than the tokenised versions, then use this additional step:

```
sapply(ttTokenized, paste, collapse = " ")
## [1] "esta unica lista hacer" "esta unica"
```